# How can i print in to the console in .asp proyect?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to print message to trough to console with   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine or Console.Writeline

Debug console don't show anything, In spring you can follow the output easily seeing the console ,I tried do in other project but I don´t have any problem

Comment: `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` should work. What type of project are you running?

Comment: Click the View Menu > Output Window, also check the dropdown in the Output Window is set to output or debug not build or something else

Comment: Is a web service, don't print anything and yes i can see the output windows but this don't have any message

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: don´t work it i use that how i can explain it in my example